# What are the costs of abstracting a type as a struct?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, linker

If we have a C function call go through an `extern inline` indirection, are there any extra costs in performance for defining that indirection with a struct of the correct size instead of the correct type? And if so; why?

*Defined as an actual type:*

```
extern inline int indirect(int x) {
  int the_function(int);
  return the_function(x);
}
```

*Defined as a char array struct:*

```
struct T { char arr[sizeof(int)]; };

extern inline struct T indirect(struct T x) {
  struct T the_function(struct T);
  return the_function(x);
}
```

Comment: yes.  and too broad for specific details, compiler, target, etc.

Comment: what has your research shown thus far, starting with disassembly and going from there?